# geth returns error with ipcapi option

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc

When I launch geth with ipcapi:

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi "eth,web3,txpool" --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,miner,net,shh,txpool,web3"
```

geth returns me an error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -ipcapi
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Seems that that flag is [no longer included](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/8b84bd283fe94a7c921fd404156e25160ac918dc/cmd/utils/flags.go). Also check `geth help`

Answer (score 0):

geth  --rpc ipcapi admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,shh,txpool,web3 --mine -rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\chaindata  --rpc --mine --minerthreads 5 --networkid 98764 init C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\CustomGenesis.json

Answer (score 0):

geth version:

*1.0.0*

support the `--ipcapi` with value `admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3`